From neo4j console, how do I connect to a remote Neo4j service
I am running Linux. I would like to connect to a remote neo4j service by using neo4j console.
I have installed a neo4j (neo4j:5.20.0) instance on a different computer. There Neo4j runs as docker swarm service via docker stack deployment.
I would like to use the command line and not the web browser to interact with the neo4j instance.
I assume neo4j console is the tool I should use. I am unable to find documentation on how to set/supply connection parameters to neo4j console.
Any examples or links to documentation would help.
Thanks.

Not sure what you mean by "neo4j console", but to use Cypher on a remote server from the command-line you can use the Cypher Shell.

Thanks, I will have a look at Cypher Shell, I hope I can also load data through it.
